# Why is quadratic programming used in Model Predictive Control when linear programming can solve the problem as well?

Tags: linear-programming, control-theory, optimal-control, quadratic-programming

Consider that we have a discrete state space model.

$$x(k+1) = Ax(k) + Bu(k) \\
y(k) = Cx(k)$$

And we want to find out what is the best inputs $u(k)$. So to do that we can create the extended observabillity matrix and the lower triangular toeplitz matrix of observability matrix times $C$ matrix.

$$F = \begin{bmatrix}
CA\\ 
CA^2\\ 
CA^3\\ 
\vdots \\ 
CA^{N_p}
\end{bmatrix} , \Phi = \begin{bmatrix}
CB &0  &0  &\cdots   & 0\\ 
CAB & CB & 0  & \cdots & 0\\ 
CA^2B& CAB & 0 &\cdots  &0 \\ 
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots \\ 
CA^{N_p-1}B & CA^{N_p-2}B & CA^{N_p-3}B & \cdots  & CA^{N_p-N_c}B 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now we want to solve $U = u_0, u_1, u_2, ... , u_n$ form this were $Y = y_0, y_1, y_2, ... , y_n$ is our reference and $x_0$ is our initial state where we are at the beginning.
$$Y = Fx_0 + \Phi U$$

To solve for that, it can be done via quadratic programming:

$$\nabla J = \frac{1}{2}U^T \Phi^T \Phi U +  \Phi^T(Y-Fx_0)U$$

Subject to:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi   \\ 
-\Phi 
\end{bmatrix}U \leq \begin{bmatrix}
b_u\\ 
-b_l
\end{bmatrix}  \\
U \geq 0
$$

Or via linear programming e.g simplex method
$$\Delta  c^T = \Phi^T (Y-F x_0)U$$
Subject to:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi   \\ 
-\Phi 
\end{bmatrix}U \leq \begin{bmatrix}
b_u\\ 
-b_l
\end{bmatrix}  \\
U \geq 0
$$

And they both having their origin formula from ordinary least squares
$$U = (\Phi^T\Phi)^{-1}\Phi^T (Y-F x_0)$$

So what's is the difference in result of $U$ ?